# I have 2 divs that overlap when re-sizing browser

Tags: html, resize, overlap

As you can see, I have the image set to responsive so it stretches accordingly when re-sizing the browser, so the image fits and keeps its ratio. That's how I want it. What I don't want is the music player to overlap with the image.

I'd also like to keep their position the way they are, centered, and next to each other.

I tried to search for a solution but everything I found was in different conditions and didn't help. I'm sure this is a stupid simple fix, I just can't wrap my head around it.
http://jsfiddle.net/6ML3s/

**HTML**

```
<body>

<img id="background-img" class="bg" border="0" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2012/191/f/6/me_by_danidrama-d56ryzq.png" alt="" ondragstart="return false" onContextMenu="return false"/>

<div class="player"><embed src="http://www.sheepproductions.com/billy/billy.swf?autoplay=true&f0=https://www.dropbox.com/s/q8fkqwom6m2t5n1/extan.mp3?dl=1&t0=&total=1" quality="high" wmode="transparent" width="200" height="10" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" /></div>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color:#B1ACA9;
}
.bg {
    height:91%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 25%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.player {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:40%;
    z-index:99999;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/6ML3s/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <img id="background-img" class="bg" border="0" src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2012/191/f/6/me_by_danidrama-d56ryzq.png" alt="" ondragstart="return false" onContextMenu="return false" />
    </div>
    <div class="player">
        <embed src="http://www.sheepproductions.com/billy/billy.swf?autoplay=false&f0=https://www.dropbox.com/s/q8fkqwom6m2t5n1/extan.mp3?dl=1&t0=&total=1" quality="high" wmode="transparent" width="200" height="10" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    display:table;
}
.container div {
    display:table-cell;
    width:49%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.container div img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Wrapped your code in a div and the image in a div. I used `width:49%` but you can adjust according to your use and requirements.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make the musicplayer a child of the image? So that the image can stay absolute and the musicplayer will not overlap.

Because I'm using a different image but I had to substitute it cause its a NSFW drawing. I'd like to keep the image stuck to the bottom of the screen with "bottom: 0;" so it needs to be absolute =/

Comment: You can't make any element a child of image. Images are self closing tags with no content. However you can try making the player it's siblings.

Comment: You can try using image as background of a div and then placing the music player inside the div. that will work for you

Comment: Actually can you help me :(.. I tried but I cant get it to work http://jsfiddle.net/6ML3s/3/

Comment: Is it possible to keep the image with percentages for resizing and attached to the bottom (bottom: 0;) when its used as a background div?

Comment: Yes, use background-position in css. You can search for options in background-position. Also try for background-size.

Comment: I can't even get the background-image to show unless I call it with <body> which defeats the whole purpose. I made sure I'm using the correct code but... lol you can tell im not good at this. Nevermind, I'll just use what I had, thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: You forgot to add semi-colon after the background-image in jsfiddle. That's the reason it wasnt working.

Comment: Thanks, silly mistake lol. I've been trying for a bit now but I cant get what I want to accomplish. Can't get the bg-img to resize or positioned where I want it. Could you please help me, I'm all about learning how to do things myself but I'm just second guessing now and getting no where. All I'm trying to do is exactly what I have in the jfiddle in my original post, but keep that empty space between the 2 elements so when it resizes too small it doesn't overlap eachother. Please, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Check the updated code here: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/6ML3s/6/  Now I have added the background-image to the div just like you wanted. Also, they won't overlap each other no matter how much you resize.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. If I wanted to flip them (player,img) how would I do that? I moved the first-child div with the bgimg to after the embed. It flips but the player now overlaps the image again. You can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/6ML3s/9/ I've disabled the player's transparency to see better. What am I doing wrong?

Also, I'm sorry if I'm being an annoyance. If I am just tell me. I really appreciate all the help you've given me.

Comment: Yeah, you need to switch the player and img div. but in css you haven't changed anything. Div:first-child selects the first child of parent. So in case if you switch the position if img and player, player becomes the first-child and the css is applied to it instead of img div. so better add a class to the img div and then assign the background styles to that class in css.